# Pytest Mock function in a class - No module named 'lib.servers.GetServers'; 'lib.servers' is not a package

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to write some test with pytest and I'd like to use a mock but I'm having issue finding the good path to use.

I'm getting this error message, No module named 'lib.servers.GetServers'; 'lib.servers' is not a package

Here's my architecture :

```
lib
-> servers.py
Tests
-> lib
    -> test_servers.py
```

Here's my class with my function i'd like to mock (get_server)

```
class GetServers:
   def get_server():
      return config
```

Here's my pytest

```
def test_config_(caplog, mocker):
    config = "test"
    mocker.patch('lib.servers.GetServer.get_server', return_value=config)
```

Do you have any idea what 'im doing wrong please ?
Thanks a lot :)

I tried many different path and i'm expecting to mock my function

Comment: What is mocker?

Answer (score 0):

> ⚠️ Warning: this type of patching is a bad practice and might be dangerous. See: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch
>
> My recommandation is to patch the value of config in `lib/server` instead of the `GetServers.get_server` method.

Using Pytest, the `monkeypatch` fixture and a lambda might fix the issue.

**Make sure to run the pytest command in the root folder of your project, not inside the `test/lib` folder.**

```py
def test_config_(monkeypatch):
    config = "test"
    monkeypatch.setattr("lib.servers.GetServers.get_server", lambda: config)
    import lib.servers

    assert lib.servers.GetServers.get_server() == config
```

Same file hierarchy:

```
lib
. servers.py
tests
. lib
  . test_servers.py
```

Comment: Still having issue with monkeypatch
```
ImportError: import error in lib.servers.GetServer: No module named 'lib.servers.GetServer'; 'lib.servers' is not a package
```

Comment: Most probable issue with this: you are not running python in the correct folder.
Make sure to run the pytest command in the root folder of your project, not inside the test/lib folder.

Comment: I'm lauching pytest from the top folder of the project :(

Comment: I will try to look further in monkeypatch

Comment: I'll investigate what can cause your issue :)

Comment: I found it Dorian, I forgot an s in a word, sorry for your time thanks for the help anyway !

Comment: Can you tell me which one?

Comment: lib.servers.GetServers.get_server

I wrote GetServer instead of GetServers